# How to display profile friends' avatars of a specific profile user?

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables in my database:

1. user_accounts    which has **id** and **avatars**
2. user_friends     which has **uid** and **fid** ( where uid = accounts id , fid = firends id)
3. Pages            which has **pid** (i.e page id ) and **uid** (i.e user id)

How to write SQL so as to display the friends avatars for a specific **pid** ?  (just like FACEBOOK display friends list for a specific user id ).

Comment: does each user have only one page, and all friends of the owner of the page would need to be shown?

Comment: SELECT avatar FROM user_accounts 
INNER JOIN user_friends on user_accounts.id = user_friends.uid
INNER JOIN pages on pages.uid = user_accounts.uid

Comment: Each user have several pages ....... only one is of profile. Other pages like fan page are also included in pages. "specific page" My question is related to is ONLY PROFILE page

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `fid` in `user_friends` table is related to an `user_accounts` `id`

```
select ua.avatars 
from user_friends uf
inner join user_accounts ua on uf.fid = ua.id
inner join pages p on p.uid = uf.uid
where p.pid = <somepid>
```

or probably clearer

```
select ua.avatars
from pages p
inner join user_friends uf on uf.uid = p.uid
inner join user_accounts ua on ua.id = uf.fid
where p.pid = <somepid>
```